# 'MSAL' : issuer is invalid

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, azure-ad-msal

I am migrating from ADAL to MSAL.

I have added the below config in angular 8 :

```
MsalModule.forRoot({
      auth: {
          clientId: "xxxxx",
          authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant",
                validateAuthority: true,
                redirectUri: window.location.href,
                postLogoutRedirectUri: "http://localhost:4200/",
                navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // set to true for IE 11
      },
    },
    {
      popUp: false,
      consentScopes: ['Directory.AccessAsUser.All',
        'user.read',
        'openid',
        'profile',
        'User.ReadWrite',
        'User.ReadBasic.All',
        'User.Read.All',
        'Group.Read.All',
        'Directory.AccessAsUser.All'
      ],
      unprotectedResources: ['https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/'],
      protectedResourceMap,
      extraQueryParameters: {}
  }),
```

Also i am trying to validate by acquiring the token

```
const loginRequest = {
    scopes: ['user.read','openid', 'profile'],
  };

 this.authService.acquireTokenSilent(loginRequest);

                   this.broadcastService.subscribe("msal:acquireTokenFailure", (payload) => {
                    console.info("acquire token failure " + JSON.stringify(payload));
                  });
                 this.broadcastService.subscribe("msal:acquireTokenSuccess", (payload) => {
                    console.info("acquire token success " + JSON.stringify(payload));
                  });
```

In .net side i have written the below code :

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                AuthenticationOptions authSettings = Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").Get<AuthenticationOptions>();


                options.Authority = authSettings.Authority;
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnTokenValidated = context =>
                    {

                        // Add the access_token as a claim, as we may actually need it
                        if (context.SecurityToken is JwtSecurityToken accessToken)
                        {
                            if (context.Principal.Identity is ClaimsIdentity identity)
                            {
                                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", accessToken.RawData));
                            }
                        }

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                        // If the request is for our hub...
                        var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                            ((path.StartsWithSegments(SignalRHub) || path.StartsWithSegments(QuillHub))))
                        {
                            // Read the token out of the query string
                            context.Token = accessToken;
                        }

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    //Both the client id and app id URI of this API should be valid audiences
                    ValidAudiences = new List<string> { authSettings.ClientId },
                };
            });
```

But when ever i try to hit the token i get acquire token success but in api side i get error saying that the The issuer 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/v2.0' is invalid

What is that i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your back-end has the v1 authority configured but you are getting a v2 token. Change the authority in your API's config to:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant/v2.0
```

Ahh, actually that might not be enough.
Looks like your front-end is getting an access token for Microsoft Graph API.
You need to get a token for your API, not MS Graph API.
To do that, specify one or more scopes registered in the Expose an API page of your API app registration.

After you do that, you might a v1 token again. So do this one first before changing the authority.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have made changes in the APP registration(azure console) manifest file and changed accessTokenAcceptedVersion to 2

Comment: @junnas thanks this helped. 1more thing in api side i am calling var currentUsername = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name; but this is returning null. How do i get the username?

Comment: That's odd. Do you see any claims on the user? I.e. in _contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims?

Comment: Then you might just need to configure the NameClaimType on the authentication options. It's possible that it is looking for a claim for the name that is not there.

Comment: How do i do that i am not sure about it

Comment: On your `options.TokenValidationParameters`, you can set the `NameClaimType` property. Set the value to the Type of the claim that contains the username you want.

Comment: is it possible to get user firstname and lastname seperately from this.msalService.getaccount()?

Comment: Based on this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens, first name and last name are not included in access tokens. You might be able to add them as additional optional claims (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims) or fetch them from MS Graph API.

Comment: Thanks for this. Just a last question is it possible to get the msal full token rather than getting it from local like this localStorage.getItem('msal.idtoken')?

Comment: I think you can only get the claim values from the account object

Comment: what i see is that in getaccount it doesnt have the bearer token. So i wanted that to pass it to api

Comment: For that you call acquireToken on the MSAL app object usually.

Comment: everytime we call it will take some time. So was just thinking if there could be a easy way

Comment: It shouldn't take time after the first time :\ MSAL should cache the tokens in local/session storage and get it from there if has not expired.

Comment: I added optional parametes from the console but i dont see that in front end. Is it something that we need to configure in frontend?

Comment: I am trying to rediect with handleRedirectCallback but it doesn't get executed. I do get an error that token renewal failed due to time out so I have kept handleRedirectCallback when we get some error but the the code inside that doesn't get executed. Can you help me what I am doing wrong?